If $\sum x_n $ converges and $x_n >0$ then $\lim nx_n =0$?
Let $\sum x_n$ be a convergent series of positive real numbers . Then prove or disprove $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }nx_n =0    $
This is option $(2)$ of Multiple choice question on sequence and series of linked question which shows a counter example and hence the assertion  false.
But can you help me find out the flaw in my following approach to show it true ?
Let me consider the power series.
$f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n t^n  $
Then $f(1)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ converges (given)
Thus the radius of convergence $R$ of $f(x)$ is greater than $1$ .
Then $f'$ has same ROC.
So $f'(1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x_n$ converges and so $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} nx_n =0$

For sums use \sum, not \Sigma.

You only know that the ROC of $f$ is at least $1$.

Interesting idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Because the radius of convergence might be equal to $1$, and $f'$ might not converge at the endpoints, even if $f$ does. And yes, the statement is false. It will become true if you also require $x_n$ to be a decreasing sequence though.

$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n}$ has a ROC equal to 1, but when you put $x=1$ it converges, which is a counterexample for your conclusion.

The radius of the convergence of the derived series is at least $1$, but it might turn out to be exactly $1$. Whether or not a power series converges at its radius of convergence is a delicate question.

Shouldn't be "at most" ?.I am confused :(

@Mark Yes, thanks. I made the correction. You could have corrected my mistake yourself.

Ahh alright @Mark  since if a power series converges for $x=x_1$ it converges for all $|x| < |x_1|  $ thus the ROC , $R \ge |x_1|$ , hence at least 1 ?

@user-492177 If the radius was smaller than $1$, the series wouldn't be able to converge at $t=1$. Since it converges at this point, the radius must be $\geq 1$.
